# Rails autoload_paths doesn't work properly in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created components folder in the root of rails 5 project and added it to autoload_paths like below:

In config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/components)
config.eager_load_paths += %W(#{config.root}/components)
```

But the files inside components doesn't load when I tested in rails console. 
I guess this is something related to cache issue... Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set eager_load as true in environment config ?

For example, in config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.eager_load = true
```